# Rails 4: Invalid route name, already in use (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Well the error is telling the truth, I have used the route name 'contact' twice, but one match is for a `get` request and the other for a `post`. I have been following the following tutorial for setting up Contact Form in Rails: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/, and the author suggests adding the following to my routes file:

```
match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
```

However that gives me the following error:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact'  (ArgumentError)
```

Here is my own `routes.rb` file:

```
Fls::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
end
```

Comment: what's version of rails you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following instead of above:

```
resource :contact, only: [:new, :create]
```

OR

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact'
```

Comment: but how does it work when you `resources :photos`for example - after doing this I can use helper `photos_path` with method :post and `photos_path` with method 'get' and it hits photos#create and photos#index respectively. i.e. seems like 2 different endpoints with the same name.

Comment: to answer my own question - [this blog states](http://itm-labs.de/blog/rails-4-upgrade-gotcha-1/) _To make it available as a named route, you have to set the as option for the first route. The second will be automatically available under the same name._ but according to this answer you an just as well put it on the second route and not the first - I have not tested this yet though.

Comment: I'm still wondering how this is possible. Just putting it one or the other doesn't work.